# Cannot install certbot cloudflare DNS

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to install `python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare` but I get following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare
```

I also trying install via `pip3` but it also don't work (bad certbot version). Have you got any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly install `python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare` (Which isn't limited on an architecture) on Raspbian over [debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare/download), so, follow the procedure:

**1.** Download the package:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-certbot-dns-cloudflare/python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare_0.39.0-1_all.deb
```

**2.** Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare_0.39.0-1_all.deb
```

Finished.

Comment: That's almost worked for me ;)

I had to download older package 0.23.0, and also manually install dependency.

Comment: [python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare_0.23.0-2~bpo9+1_all.deb](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/all/python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare/download)

Comment: Yes, I already found it ;)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you try to install `python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare` using **apt** or **apt-get**. On my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian I get with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare
Listing... Done
python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare/stable 0.23.0-2 all
```

This means that the package is available in the default Raspbian repositories which are addressed with:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

So you have a problem with your installation that may impact your work and your updates in the future if you install the package direct without using the package manager. You will not have any dependencies and the package manager does not update it. Your next question about unknown error messages are bound to happen.

Comment: Can you show me `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @rechandler I have updated the answer.

Comment: I had old Rasbian version - Stretch. After update I've got this package in repo.

Comment: @rechandler You have accepted the answer to download the package from debian. Does it run on stretch without backports?

Comment: I downloaded [this](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/all/python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare/download) and it worked

Comment: @rechandler OK, that's the backported version but not the package from the accepted answer. That was confusing me.